# Need Better Solution for Simple JavaScript Pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, try-catch

I have rather verbose code for what seems like there must be a better solution:

I need to find the index of an array based on the object IDs. I originally had code as such:

```
idx = (state.store.addresses || []).findIndex(x => x.location == location_name)
if (idx > -1) { /* do something */}
```

But then I got the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'addresses' of undefined
```

I figured that the short circuiting operator would cause it to jump to using the blank array `[]` upon an error like this, thus returning `-1`.

---

Because that solution didn't work, I'm wrapping up 8 of these statements in `try...catch` statements and this code is becoming long and verbose.

Is there any better way to handle this code other than the following?

```
try {
    idx = state.store.addresses.findIndex(x => x.location == location_name)
    state.store.addresses[idx]['deleted'] = false
    set(state.store.addresses[idx], 'deleted', false)
} catch (e) {}

try {
    idx = state.store.customer.addresses.findIndex(x => x.location == location_name)
    state.store.customer.addresses[idx]['deleted'] = false;
    set(state.store.customer.addresses[idx], 'deleted', false)
} catch (e) {}

// 5 more of these
```

Comment: You could avoid that if you'd ensure your data structures always contained those properties, or if you'd implement `state` or `state.store` as an object with a method that does what you need, e.g. `state.store.setAddressState(location_name, false)`.

Comment: If you have 8 of these, write a function for them where you pass in the array!